# Linq query: where condition yields an empty sequence even if there should be one match

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have an `IEnumerable<TextBox>`. One of the element has a `Tag`. I want to filter my first `IEnumerable` in this way:

```
IEnumerable<TextBox> longDescContainersTag = 
    longDescContainers.Where(i => i.Tag == "DescrOp");
```

The where condition doesn't work, it simply doesn't find any TextBoxes, the sequence is empty. But if I do a quick watch of `longDescContainers` it has an element with Tag "DescrOp".

Do you have some suggestions?

Comment: Add `.ToList()` at the end

Comment: Can you specify "doesn't work"?

Comment: Define "*doesn't work*"? Please include a small code snippet that reproduces the problem. The check you have at the moment is case-sensitive...just a thought.

Comment: You want to *exclude* a `TextBox` which its `Tag` property equals `DescrOp` from the list? Or you want to *include* that TextBox only?

Comment: To add to what Milen has said, longDescContainers will be lazily evaluated. It wont be filled with data until longDescContainersTag  is used further in the code. Hence the ToList()

Comment: "Doesn't work" means that the query returns empty IEnumerable. But I'm sure that there is almost one element in the first list

Comment: What is returned from `longDescContainersTag.Count()`? Can you show the code where you assign the `Tag` and/or where you create the other query `longDescContainers`?

Comment: Do you really want to filter by `TextBox.Tag`? I'm not sure whether TextBox is Winforms or WPF, either way is `Tag` set to a string?

Comment: It was a way. Otherwise I don't know how to Select the textbox I want

Comment: Use i.Tag.ToString() == "DescrOp", instead. It happens because Tag is an object and you are equating directly with a string. See my answer below

Comment: Perfect it works with ToString(). Thx a lot!

Comment: @Galma88: you might have noticed the compiler warning that you are mistakenly comparing by reference, haven't you? Normally that is not a problem with strings since they are interned. But under some circumstances they are not interned(f.e. if you evaluate them in the debugger or use the string constructor or they are not literal strings).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear from your question but I'm assuming your `where`-condition is correct but you don't get any result although the source collection does contain an element where the condition *should* match.

I say *should* because `Control.Tag` is an object, and using `i.Tag == "DescrOp"` will do a comparison by reference instead of by value.

This might or might not return `true` even if the strings are equal. What you should do is cast `i.Tag` to string first, i.e. `(string)i.Tag == "DescrOp"`.

Comment: Good catch, although i'm fairly sure that string interning makes them the same reference.

Comment: @bit: you got the downvotes on the original answer which was: _"You need to watch `longDescContainersTag` and not `longDescContainers`"_

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, but that depends where the string in the Tag comes from. If it's hardcoded there too then the reference comparison will return true (most likely), but if it's the result of a DB query then not.

Comment: @dirk: if it's hard coded it's `true` for sure, if not the query must be materialized anyway, so at that point the string is used from the interned string(imho). But then it's an interesting question. Maybe it's also just a debugger issue because the debugger will not intern strings.

Comment: `((object)new string("Hello".ToCharArray()) == "Hello")` for example returns `false`. But in any case you should not rely on strings being interned or not when clearly you want to compare by value and not by reference.

Comment: @Dirk: but just because you use the string constructor which is one of the ways to avoid string interning. I doubt that this is the case here.

Answer (score 1):

1- Are you sure .Tag contains string value? In some cases when we watching the watch window shows name of an object. Actually cals "ToString()" method of object and shows it. I think you can use this code:

```
IEnumerable<TextBox> longDescContainersTag = 
    longDescContainers.Where(i => i.Tag.ToString() == "DescrOp");
```

2- Are you sure all objects in "`longDescContainers`" is of type "`TextBox`"?
I don't know what is "longDescContainers" object, but in some container objects we need to cast their sub items(controls) like this code "`longDescContainers.cast<TextBox>().where(....)`".
If you not sure all objects in "longDescContainers" is TextBox you can try this code:

```
    IEnumerable<TextBox> longDescContainersTag = longDescContainers.
    Where(i => i.GetType() == typeof(TextBox) && i.Tag == "DescrOp").
Select(t=> (TextBox)t);
```

If longDescContainersTag  contains even any object of type "TextBox" that tag is "DescrOp" the code above returns it.

You can use compound of "1" and "2" and use the following code:

```
    IEnumerable<TextBox> longDescContainersTag = longDescContainers.
    Where(i => i.GetType() == typeof(TextBox) && i.Tag.ToString() == "DescrOp")
.Select(t=> (TextBox)t);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `longDescContainers` is a collection of `TextBox`. I suspect that comparing `Tag` (object) to `"DescrOp"` (string) fails.. Try to use `ToString()`..

```
IEnumerable<TextBox> longDescContainersTag = longDescContainers.Where(i => i.Tag!=null && i.Tag.ToString() == "DescrOp");
```

Comment: The point the OP is making is they have checked `longDescContainers` and it has an item that *should* match the filter, but isn't.

Comment: @bit Presumably those downvotes were before you completely changed your answer...